# PHP to run at intervals within foreach but with added randomness

Tags: php, foreach

So i have a foreach and i want to insert a bit of html every say 6 times or maybe 11 times the loop is run.

So my insert on each 13th record

```
if ($i % 13 == 0) { 
}
```

trouble is i want to add a bit more randomness to it.

Totally forgotten what this is called as well

Comment: well you can use rand() to get random number.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: but how can i get random past 13? so random after 13 if that makes sense?

Comment: As in, random that won't be below 13

Comment: "Totally forgotten what this is called as well" `%` is the modulus operator.

Comment: @JamieHutber - rand(min, max) so you could do rand(13, 20) to get a random number between 13 -> 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will make some code execute `$percentage` of the time every loop. For example you could set `$percent = 20` then your code will execute only 20% of the time each iteration.

```
$value = rand( 0, 100 ); // Set your ranges (min/max)
$percent = 0; // Set percentage

if ( $percent >= $value )
{
    // Will only execute $percentage of the time each loop
}
```

Comment: sweet dude, been experimenting with this and its working a treat :)